# Does Nuxt and React have a GUI like Vue CLI3 that includes a convenient template generation wizard and build button?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have made several products with Vue CLI 3.

However, I have never created a new project using Nuxt.

I am also interested in React because its market share is high.
However, I have never created a new project.

The reason is that I'm used to the convenience of Vue CLI 3.

- Convenient template creation wizard
- GUI with build buttons

I like the environment that exists.

For me, too much freedom in naming and arranging files is a problem.
I can't decide on the best one, so I can't develop fast.

There are two things I expect from Nuxt and React:.

```sh
$ vue create my-project
$ vue ui
```

Do Nuxt and React currently have those features?

If it does not exist,
Please tell me how you solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have used vue cli then I'm pretty sure you can use nuxt's [create-nuxt-app](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app)

It is easy just as it seems. The cli will guide you throughout the initialization process.

Comment: Thank you . I look forward to hearing about React.

Comment: If it solves your issue then please mark it. thanks.